# How to replicate jQuery DIV toggle "slide in"

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

Caveat: I am a designer not a developer.

Please view [this webpage](http://www.paspaley.com/), click `SUBSCRIBE` in the bottom nav menu, and see the newsletter subscription `nav#subscribe` "slide" into view / slide out of view on each click.

[image]

What is the simplest way to replicate the `nav#subscribe` sliding in / sliding out of view?

Comment: If you can show your code, then we can help you.. Anyways for your reference, you can go with **[`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code for slide toogle:

```
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs. Congratulations it works.
</p>
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
</body>
```

If you can share your code we can help more.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Raghbendra. :-) Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can just simulate the "SUBSCRIBE" click/trigger by

```
$('footer a[rel=subscribe]').click();
```

Try this command in console window, this will slide-in the nav#subscribe and triggering click again will slide-out.

Hope this helps?